# NGINX nice url configuration

Tags: nginx, friendly-url

On NGINX I am trying to figure out how to keep nice URL in address bar after redirecting to the php file. I have tried all the mentioned below in the code and it works fine but no matter if use redirect or proxy, I still see [www.mydomain.com/products.php](http://www.mydomain.com/products.php) in the address bar. And I need to keep the address looking as [www.mydomain.com/products](http://www.mydomain.com/products). Any ideas please?

```
server {
server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com;

index index.html index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /products {
    #rewrite ^/products$ /products.php last;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /products.php;
    proxy_pass http://localhost/products.php;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I overcomplicated that, the simplest way works fine.

```
location /products {
  rewrite ^/products /products.php last;
}
```